# Strip all trailing occurrences of a character

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV that needs cleaning up. It has records along the lines of

```
1, a[]b[][][], c[]d[][][]
2, a[]b[]c[]d[]e, a[]b[]c[]d[]e
```

Any occurrences of trailing `[]` within a field need to be removed from rows which are then written to a new file. For example, in this case line 1 would become `1, a[]b, c[]d` and line 2 would be unchanged.

Here's as far as I have gotten:

```
import csv

new_rows = []

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:    
        new_row = [i.split(',').rstrip('[]') for i in row] #won't work since this is a list, not a string
        new_rows.append(new_row) 

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(new_rows)
```

I know rstrip only works on strings and not lists. I'm a bit of a novice with Python and can't quite figure it out, can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: Is there a reason you are splitting on `|`? I don't see it in the input. You can try `rstrip` before `split`.

Comment: Good catch, thanks. I was jumping back and forth between csvs and overlooked that.

Comment: As per @chepner's answer, there is no need to save your results to an intermediate `new_rows` list.  Just write them out as you go.  It's simpler to read and more memory efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv

new_rows = []

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as inf:
    with open('output.csv', 'wb') as outf:
        reader = csv.reader(inf)
        writer = csv.writer(outf)
        for row in reader: 
            new_row = [ field.rstrip('[]') for field in row ]
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Prior to Python 2.7, you can combine the context managers into one `with` statement with

```
import contextlib
with contextlib.nested(open('input.csv', 'rb'), open('output.csv', 'wb')) as (inf, outf):
    reader = ...
```

In Python 2.7, the `with` statement itself was modified to support this:

```
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as inf, open('output.csv', 'wb') as outf:
```

although implicit line continuation is not available; to split across two lines, you must
use a line-continuation character:

```
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as inf,\
     open('output.csv', 'rb') as outf:
```

Comment: Note that if you don't like the multiple indents caused by nested `with` statements, you can smash them together on a single line `with open('input.csv', 'rb') as inf, open('output.csv', 'wb') as outf:`.  Also note that the smashed together line can be put on two lines by using a line continuation (`\\`) (which I prefer as being the best of both having seperate lines but only one indent).

Comment: Multiple context managers with a single `with` statement is not supported prior to Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

Almost there, looks like just an errant split.

```
import csv

new_rows = []

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:    
        new_row = [x.rstrip('[]') for x in row]
        new_rows.append(new_row) 

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(new_rows)
```

On input of:

```
1, a[]b[][][], c[]d[][][]
2, a[]b[]c[]d[]e, a[]b[]c[]d[]e
```

I get the following:

```
1, a[]b, c[]d
2, a[]b[]c[]d[]e, a[]b[]c[]d[]e
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It's so frequently something simple like that.